# Constructor: is it the right one being called?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, boolean

In your opinion, which constructor will be called?

```
class Element {
public:
    Element(bool b = true, bool c = true);
    Element(const std::string s, bool b = true, bool c = true);
};
...
Element element("something", true);
```

Wrong! The first one.

Do I have to restart Stroustrup's book from the beginning?

I tried without the const, but nothing changes.

It seems that a char* looks more like a bool than a std::string.

With this code everything is all right:

```
Element element(string("something"), true);
```

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

OS: Windows 7

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question in the edit. Is there (another) real question here?

Comment: side note: please don't pass `std::string`s by value; const reference is probably more efficient here.

Comment: tenfour: yes, a const reference is what I used at the beginning. I tried to remove the reference to see if things improved.

Comment: Charles Bailey: well, mine was not an answer. I wanted to avoid the explicit use of string().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built-in conversion from pointer types to `bool`, non-null pointers are converted to `true` and null pointer values to `false`.

`std::string` is a user-defined type (in the loosest sense of the word user) so the conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` won't be preferred over the built-in `const char*` to `bool` conversion. You have to do something like this (or add an overload which takes a `const char *`).

```
Element element( std::string("something"), true);
```

Comment: And making the first parameter a string reference wouldn't make a difference?

Comment: @Klaim: No, you'd still have to convert from `const char*` to `std:string` whether you're passing it by value or binding that temporary to a `const` reference parameter.

Comment: Yes, I added an overload which takes a const char*, and things work better. Thank's.

Answer (score 2):

.

C++ Standard (N1905) says,

> $4.1 **Standard conversions are implicit
> conversions defined for built-in
> types**. Clause 4 enumerates the full
> set of such conversions. A standard
> conversion sequence is a sequence of
> standard conversions in the following
> order:
>
> [...]
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the
> following set: integral promotions,
> floating point promotion, integral
> conversions, floating point
> conversions, floating-integral
> conversions, **pointer conversions**,
> pointer to member conversions, **and
> boolean  conversions.**
>
> [...]
>
> $4.4 In general, **an implicit
> conversion sequence (13.3.3.1)
> consists of a standard conversion
> sequence followed by a user-defined
> conversion** followed by another
> standard conversion sequence.
>
> ## 4.12 Boolean conversions
>
> $4.12.1 An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration,
> **pointer**, or pointer to member type **can be converted to an rvalue of type bool**. A zero value, null
> pointer value, or null member pointer
> value is converted to false **any
> other value is converted to true**.

## 13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences

> 2 When comparing the basic forms of
> implicit conversion sequences (as
> defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> — **a standard
> conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a
> better conversion sequence than a
> user-defined conversion sequence** or an
> ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>
> — a
> user-defined conversion sequence
> (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion
> sequence than an ellipsis conversion
> sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Hope, it explains well the behaviour shown by your code. :-)

Also, this is a good read :

[Implicit conversion sequences (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fimplicit_conversion_sequences.htm)

.

Comment: You should really quote 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] to explain why the boolean conversion is chosen over the user-defined conversion sequence.

Comment: @Charles & @Nawaz: Thank you both for your answers. I will leave Charles' as the accepted one because it is more "practical", but I appreciate Nawaz's exposed theoretical aspects.